# How to search and correct html tags and attributes?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, parsing

In my application, I have to fix all the closing tags of the `<img>` tag as shown below. Instead of closing the `<img>` with a `>`, it should close with `/>`.

Is there any easy way to search for all the `<img>` in this text and fix the `>` ?

(If it is closed with a `/>` already then there is no action required).

Other question, if there is no "width" or "height" to the `<img>` specified, what is the best way to solve the issue?

Download all the images and get the corresponding attributes of width and height, then add them back to the string?

The correct `<img>` tag is the one that closes with `/>` and have the valid width & height.

```
<a href="http://www.cultofmac.com/daily-deals749-mac-mini-1199-3-0ghz-imac-new-mac-pros/52674"><img align="left" hspace="5" width="150" src="http://s3.dlnws.com/images/products/images/749000/749208-large" alt="" title=""></a>
Apple today unleashed a number of goodies, including giving iMacs and Mac Pros more oomph with new processors and increased storage options. We have those deals today, along with many more items for the Mac lover. Along with the refreshed line of iMacs and Mac Pros, we’ll also look at a number of software deals [...]
<p><a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/DL_-gOGSR1JMzKDbErt1EG3re3I/0/da"><img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/DL_-gOGSR1JMzKDbErt1EG3re3I/0/di" border="0" ismap></a><br>
<a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/DL_-gOGSR1JMzKDbErt1EG3re3I/1/da"><img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/DL_-gOGSR1JMzKDbErt1EG3re3I/1/di" border="0" ismap></a></p><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/cultofmac/bFow/~4/Mq5iLOaT50k" height="1" width="1">
```

Comment: I use the TTStyledTextLabel from Three20 library to show the parsed text into the view and because the text does not come with correct format, I need to correct it before passing to the StyledText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions will solve the problem with closing your tags correctly - make sure whatever you're using to edit your code supports regular expression searching, and then search for something like this (assuming that all of your unclosed image tags end with a ">):

```
\<img (.*?)"\>
```

and replace it with this:

```
<img $1" />
```

As far as the bit about the width and height attributes, if you're trying to display the images at their regular width and height, you shouldn't need them. The only time you should need width and height is if you're displaying the image at a different size than the original image's size, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: hi Steve, thanks for your answer. As far as I know, the TTStyledTextLabel from the Three20 Library does not show correctly the image if the width & height are not set, it assumes that the image has a CGRectZero so nothing is shown. That's why I need to adjust the input. Thanks for the regular suggestion again, I have not thought of it before :)